# How to return only the strings ending in a punctuation mark?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I want to build a method, which returns only the strings that end with a punctuation mark. The problem is that when I compile it says that it couldn't find the 'i', so what should I do?

```
public static String ktheFjalite(String[] s){
    int nrFjaleve = 0;
    int nrZanoreve = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j <s.length; j++){
            if (s[j].charAt(j) == ' '){
                nrFjaleve++;
            }
        }
    for (int k = 0; k < s.length; k++){
            if (s[k].contains("a")||s[k].contains("e")||s[k].contains("i")||s[k].contains("o")||s[k].contains("u")||s[k].contains("y")){
                nrZanoreve++;
            }
        }

    if(s[i].endsWith(".")||s[i].endsWith("!")||s[i].endsWith("?")||s[i].endsWith("...")){
        if(nrFjaleve<=6){
            if(nrZanoreve<=8) {
                return (Arrays.toString(s));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `i`meant to be? Can you show a [mcve]?

Comment: can you show more code that method completely

Comment: @Deadpool here the full code of the method

Comment: You are missing a loop that uses `i` as an increment.

Comment: @achAmháin but if I use a loop how can I check the strings of the array, and return it if true?

Comment: well I am saying the same thing: I cannot find the declaration/definition of 'i' either in your code.

Comment: @kai so how can I achieve my goal without the ‘i’? How can I compare string in an if statement there without it?

Comment: sorry but it makes no sense to me(and the compiler) if you request "i" without saying what 'i' is. Is 'i' a String or a slice of bread or what is it???!!! You need to define it.

Comment: what if multiple strings in array ends with punctuation mark? @AltinMullaidrizi then which one you want to return?

Comment: @Deadpool it should return all of them.

Comment: the you should return `String[]` instead of `String` and also what are these conditions `if(nrFjaleve<=6)` and `if(nrZanoreve<=8)`? @AltinMullaidrizi

Comment: @kai I completely understand you, and I know where the mistake stands, but I am asking for help on how can I check if a string ends with punctuation mask, with this method, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Deadpool oh okay will change that. P.s. these condition are not in english, so they probably don’t make sense. nrFjaleve<=6 means number of words<=6, and nrZanoreve<=8 means number of vowels<=8.

Comment: @AltinMullaidrizi find if an ending matches works just the way you do it in your code. Thats fine. But i am not so sure if you are testing the ending of the right thing(which is undefined).

Comment: You first for loop is bound to throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` if you have more strings than the length of the string you are checking. Since you use the same variable `j`, which goes up to `s.length`, if `s.length > s[j].length` you will get an exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way not using regex or patterns:

Consider `String marks = "...";` where the ellipsis represents all of the characters that you consider to be punctuation marks.

Then note that the final character of a String s is `c = s.charAt(s.length() - 1); //Minus one or OutOfBoundsException`

Then `marks.contains(c)` will be true if the last character of the String is a punctuation mark.

Comment: Just account for the empty string and it's perfect, though that can probably be done in OP's own code

Comment: And the OP also needs to consider whether there might be whitespace following the punctuation. Would that be considered a String ending in a punctuation or not?

Answer (score 0):

I would use regex to find all words that end with punctuation and return it in a list. For more information on regex click [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

```
private static List<String> findPunctuation(String sentence) {
    List<String> neededWords = new ArrayList<String>();
    String[] words = sentence.split(" ");

    for (String word : words)
        if (word.matches(".*[\\?!\\.]")) 
            neededWords.add(word);

    return neededWords;
}
```

This may not be a perfect solution for you but it should give you some direction.

**EDIT**

If you only want to return the word if there are x amount of words you can achieve that with this:

```
private static String findPunctuation(String sentence) {

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?:.* ){6,8}(.*[\\?!\\.])$");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(sentence);

    while(m.find())
        return m.group(1);

    return null;
}
```

Hope this helps.